# sending xhr with api at the beginning of url address

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

my target website sends #XHR request based on what I do on the #webpage. I want to send the XHR request via #Javascript. the problem that I face is that the XHR request URL has a "api" at the beginning (that's api.something.com) and I can't send the request. can anybody help me why I can't do that and is there any solution to pass it away?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is stopping you from sending an XHR request to a URL that starts with "api"? What is your code?

Comment: i get [HTTP/2 401 Unauthorized error